# Simulate form post using http client in Android app?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, http

So, I'm currently developing an app for a service which  has a json-based (unfortunately) **read only API**. Retrieving content is no problem at all, however the only way to post content is using a form on their site which location is a PHP script. The service is open source so I know which fields the form expects, but whatever I send, it always results in a *BAD REQUEST*.

I captured the network traffic inside my browser and as far as I can see, the browser constructs a multipart form request, however when I copy the request and invoke it again using a REST client, a *BAD REQUEST* gets returned.

Is there a way to construct a http request in Android that simulates a form post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's readonly I think you wouldn't be able to make requests with POST (it's assume for editing or adding things).

If you let me make you an advise, I recommend you using this project as a Library.

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It makes you easy deal with apis, control network problems etc.

You can find a sample of use there.

You only have to:

1. Build your URL
2. Tell the component to execute in POST mode
3. Build your JSON

As I told you, I don't know even if it will work.

I hope it helps!!!